# Oracle find data volume per column

Tags: oracle

Could someone please help me to develop a query to find the **data volume** specific to a column. So we have a clob and blob data type column where we need to identify the size of those two columns relative to a date field. symbolically the logic would be

`select size(of column type clob/blob) from {table} where date (another column) >= {}`

The idea here is to identify the size of data eligible for house keeping.

### Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below queries,

You can filter particular `table` and `column` if needed.

***Using DBA_ views:***

```
SELECT l.owner,
       l.table_name,
       l.column_name,
       l.segment_name,
       l.tablespace_name,
       round(s.bytes/1024/1024,2) size_mb
FROM dba_lobs l
JOIN dba_segments s 
  ON s.owner = l.owner 
 AND s.segment_name = l.segment_name
ORDER BY 6 DESC;
```

***Using User_ views:***

```
SELECT l.table_name,
       l.column_name,
       l.segment_name,
       l.tablespace_name,
       round(s.bytes/1024/1024,2) size_mb
FROM user_lobs l
JOIN user_segments s 
  ON s.segment_name = l.segment_name
ORDER BY 5 DESC;
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks much. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH` to get the length of a CLOB or BLOB.

#### Query

```
WITH
    sample_data
    AS
        (SELECT EMPTY_CLOB () AS clob_val FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT EMPTY_CLOB () || 'some text' AS clob_val FROM DUAL)
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (clob_val, 200, 1)     AS clob_text,
       DBMS_LOB.getlength (clob_val)          AS clob_length
  FROM sample_data;
```

#### Result

```
   CLOB_TEXT    CLOB_LENGTH
____________ ______________
                          0
some text                 9
```

Comment: Thanks EJ, I have made my question clear, its bit different